# How do I find the symmetrical point B given the centre of symmetry C and another point A?

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a point $A (-2k; 3)$ and a point $B$ that is symmetrical to the point A given the centre of symmetry $C (-1; 0)$.

I tried applying the following formula, where $x_o$ and $y_0$ are the coordinates of the centre of symmetry, $C$, and $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates of the point $A$:

$$\begin{cases}
x_B = 2x_o - x = 2(-1) - (-2k ) = 2k - 2\\ 
y_B = 2y_0 - y\ = 2(0) - 3 = -3 
\end{cases}
$$

I find $B(2k-2; -3$) as coordinates of the point $B$. Though, putting that into a graph, it doesn't seem that the point $C$ is the centre of symmetry of $A$ and $B$.

[image]

I suppose I didn't calculate the coordinates of the point $B$ correctly. Could you please spot my mistake?

Comment: $A+B=2C$, right?

Comment: Are you referring to the coordinates of the points? Thanks!

Comment: You are correct. yor $B$, for $k=1$, is $(0,-3)$.

Comment: Thank you @EmilioNovati! Is the graph correct, then? Shouldn't $C$ stay in the middle?

Comment: The graph is wrong. In Your graph $B$ is $(0,0)$, not $(0,-3)$. If you put the correct $B$ then $C$ stay in the midle.

Comment: Thank you so much @Emilio. I appreciate your help. Please feel free to post your comments as an answer, and I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculations in OP are correct, but the graph is wrong. For $k=1$ the point $B$ is $(0,-3)$ and not $(0,0)$ as in the graph. If you correct than $C$ is the middle point between $A$ and $B$.